# Postgres random number by factor of 10

Tags: postgresql, random

I need a way to generate a random number where I specify the size (size in number of zeros).
ie.

- numbers 0-9 > no zeros
- numbers 10-99 > one zero
- numbers 100-999 > two zeros
- ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this operation. It multiplies `random()` by the amount (* 10) to move the decimal up and then discards the decimals.

```sql
select trunc(random() * concat('1', repeat('0', numberOfZeros + 1))::int);
```

or maybe store it in a function

```sql
create function randomPositiveNumberByFactor(zeros int)
returns int language plpgsql as $$
BEGIN
    return trunc(random() * concat('1', repeat('0', zeros + 1))::int);
END
$$;
```

A few examples
`select randomPositiveNumberByFactor(0);`: numbers 0-9
`select randomPositiveNumberByFactor(1);`: numbers 10-99
`select randomPositiveNumberByFactor(2);`: numbers 100-999